# Write Glib::ustring async to file with Glibmm (Gio::File)

Tags: file, asynchronous, glib, gio, glibmm

I just could not find any example code to asynchronously write a [Glib::ustring](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1ustring.html) (or simply a string for that matter) to a file using glibmm ([Gio::File](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGio_1_1File.html)).

Can any one provide an example or link to one?

Answer (score 0):

There's [`Gio::File::replace_contents_async()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGio_1_1File.html#ad33b24a7942429157f47379f4353378c) which will write a string in the form of a `const char*` or `std::string&`.